# Calculate $\int_0^1\ln{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am looking for the fastest possible way to calculate:

$$\int_0^1\ln{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}dx$$

The integral appeared on an integration bee where only a few minutes are given to calculate it, so please do not hesitate to use shortcuts in your solution, even if they involve advanced mathematics. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint:$$\int_0^1f(x)~dx+\int_0^1f(-x)~dx=\int_{-1}^1f(x)~dx$$And$$\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$$

Comment: Or perhaps,$$\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$$And apply integration by parts. Whatever method suits you best...

Comment: Oh... changes... well, $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$ still applies, and then integrate by parts + power rule.

Comment: Mathematica gives the primitive function $\frac{1}{2} \left(-x-\log (-x)+\log \left(1-\sqrt{x+1}\right)-\log \left(\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{x+1}+2\right)-\log \left(\sqrt{x+1}+1\right)+2 (x+1) \log \left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{x+1}\right)+\log \left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{x+1}+2\right)+2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-1\right)$

Comment: If it is not too bothersome would you mind posting your full solution? I have tried squaring the inside of the logarithm and multiplying the outside by 1/2 and then performing integration by parts with other part x. However I have not had any success.

Comment: @dromastyx Ah, perhaps there is a method to achieve the definite integral without a full calculation of the indefinite integral? As I said, I got this problem from an integration bee challenging problem website so I do believe the solution is not that complicated.

Comment: You question currently has 2 close votes with close reason [missing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Perhaps adding a link to the competition you mentioned would add at least some context. (Still the question is whether close voters would consider that sufficient.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note 
$$ (\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})^2=2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})$$
and so
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1\ln(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\ln\left[2\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right]dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\ln2+\frac12\int_0^1\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\ln2+\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1+\cos t)d\sin t\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\ln2+\frac12\bigg[\ln(1+\cos t)\sin t\bigg|_0^{\pi/2}+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2t}{1+\cos t}dt\bigg]\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\ln2+\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\cos t)dt\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\ln2+\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-1\right)\\
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$\int_0^1\ln{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}dx=\int_0^1\ln\sqrt{1+x}\left({1+\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}}\right)dx$$
and  after separation for second integral let $x=\cos2t$.

Comment: How do you use $\sin 2t$ in any useful way ? Making it $2 \cos t \sin t$ doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}J=\int_0^1\ln{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}dx\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $\displaystyle y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$,

$\begin{align}J&=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{(1+x)^2}\,dx+2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\\
&=\ln 2\left[\frac{-1}{1+x}\right]_0^1+\left(\left[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\right)+2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\\
&=\left(-\frac{\ln 2}{2}+\ln 2\right)+\frac{\ln 2}{2}+\left[\frac{1}{1+x}\right]_0^1+2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\\
&=\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}+2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\\
&=\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}+2\left(\left[-\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{1+x}\right]_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{1}{2(1+x)(1+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x}}\,dx\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}+\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x}}\,dx\\
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $\displaystyle y=\sqrt{x}$,

$\begin{align}J&=-\frac{1}{2}+\int_0^1\frac{2}{(1+x^2)(1+x)}\,dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}+\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\,dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}+\Big[\ln(1+x)\Big]_0^1+\Big[\arctan x\Big]_0^1-\frac{1}{2}\Big[\ln(1+x^2)\Big]_0^1\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}+\ln 2+\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2\\
&=\boxed{\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\sqrt a+\sqrt b=\sqrt{a+b+2\sqrt{ab}}$ and then rewrite the integral as
$$\int \ln(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})dx=\int \ln \left(\left(2+2\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^{1/2}\right)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int \ln\left(2+2\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)dx$$
Substitute $x=\sin t \implies dx=\cos t dt$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int \ln(2+2\cos t)\cos t dt$$
This can easily be integrated by parts:
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2+2\cos t)\sin t-\int\frac{-\sin^2 t}{2+2\cos t}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2+2\cos t)\sin t-\int \frac{(\cos t+1)(\cos t-1)}{2(1+\cos t)}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2+2\cos t)\sin t-\frac{1}{2}\int(\cos t-1)dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2+2\cos t)\sin t+\frac{t-\sin t}{2}+C$$
When evaluating the original integral, remember to change integration limits to $0\to\pi/2$.